# Creating realtime user-presence detector server-side for android app

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, ejabberd, openfire

I am creating an android game where the user should be able to see other users that are currently online when answering questions and should be able to interact with them - ask questions and chat basically. No state will be saved after the user has interacted with other users - that part of the app does not save chat history nor does it save users online. I was looking at ejabberd and open fire or do i go with GCM?

Answer (score 0):

Google Cloud Messaging, now rebranded on it's newer version, [Firebase Cloud Messaging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/) -- is a service commonly and mainly used for push notifications. I don't see how you could use this to build a Presence System, so no.

You might want to look into [Firebase Realtime Database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/), specially this Firebase Blog on [creating a Presence System](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2013/06/how-to-build-presence-system.html) with it.

Comment: With all that said, asking for suggestions here on Stack Overflow is *off topic*, if you didn't intend to ask it that way, your post could still be qualified as *too broad*.

Comment: Will check that out . Thanks AI